# Tree graph showing all root, parent and child nodes (even duplicates) with anytree

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, tree, anytree

I am currently trying to create a tree diagram from a dataframe that holds certain scripts that need to be executed in a certain order depending on their `parent/child` relationship. However, I am not receiving the correct number of children. My DataFrame looks like this below:

[image]

And this is the code I have so far:

```
from anytree import Node, RenderTree
def add_nodes(nodes, parent, child):
    if parent not in nodes:
        nodes[parent] = Node(parent)
    if child not in nodes:
        nodes[child] = Node(child)
    nodes[child].parent = nodes[parent]

nodes = {}
for parent, child in zip(df["parent_script"],df["child_script"]):
    add_nodes(nodes, parent, child)

roots = list(df[~df["parent_script"].isin(df["child_script"])]["parent_script"].unique())
for root in roots:
    for pre, _, node in RenderTree(nodes[root]):
        print("%s%s" % (pre, node.name))
```

I have 3 roots and several parents that are displayed correctly, but the children seem to go missing after they have been included once.

Results I get:

[image]

I think because of this logic, I am not receiving the full results I expect.

```
if child not in nodes:
        nodes[child] = Node(child)
    nodes[child].parent = nodes[parent]
```

I need all the children to be inside the tree. So for example after the 3rd Root `(00_06_MaxBIS_v2-2.sql)` has `00_07_AnlagenDatenLaden_v1-7.sql` as a child but is missing the `00_Gebietsstrukturen_v1-2.sql`.

Is there any way to include duplicate children and have them inside the tree correctly? And what kind of logic can I use to receive the expected results?